# brms model not converging

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization, non-linear-regression, stan

I have this brms model

```
library(brms)
library(dplyr)
x = rep( c(-20:20,-20:20), 5)
y = c(x[1:41]^2, (x[42:82]+5)^2)
group = c(rep("A",41), rep("B",41) )
data = data.frame( x= x, y = y , group = group)
f = brm(y~ gp(x, cov ="exp_quad") +(1|group), data = data, control = list( adapt_delta = .95) )
f
```

and the model does not fit. I get this error

```
Warning messages:
1: The model has not converged (some Rhats are > 1.1). Do not analyse the results! 
We recommend running more iterations and/or setting stronger priors. 
2: There were 1644 divergent transitions after warmup. Increasing adapt_delta above 0.95 may help.
See http://mc-stan.org/misc/warnings.html#divergent-transitions-after-warmup
```

Any idea how to get this to  fit ?

Comment: `We recommend ... setting stronger priors.` See https://betanalpha.github.io/assets/case_studies/gp_part1/part1.html and especially part 3 that is linked from there.

Comment: Also, it looks like your synthetic data is singular, in that there is no variance. Many model fitting algorithms have trouble with such data. Try it with modifying **y** with an error term, like `rnorm(length(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

Brian is most likely correct, you have created some test data that does not have any variance. Assuming this was a toy dataset for example, and you are working with a real dataset, you need to follow the directions in the warning message. I would try calling brm with the changes that I am making here:
`f = brm(y~ gp(x, cov ="exp_quad") + (1|group), data = data, control = list( adapt_delta = .99), iter = 6000)`

adapt_delta is always a value between 0 and 1, so if you get a warning message that you need to set it higher than 0.99, you could try 0.999. You didn't specify the number of iterations in your call, so it went with the default, which is 2000 I believe. I have tripled that. Also, if you have multiple cores on your computer, you should be setting `cores = 4` in your call so that each chain can run on its own core.